# Summing intervals

Tags: algorithm

I have to sum intervals like these:

```
1..6
2..4
The result is 1..6, so there are 6 numbers in the end.
```

Here's another example:

```
4..6
8..10
14..16
4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16, the size is 9.
```

Now, I have to do this in O(N). Here's a not-so-good approach I quickly came up with using the STL:

```
#include <set>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n;
  scanf("%d", &n);

  set<int> numbers;
  int a, b;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    for (int u = a; u <= b; u++) {
      numbers.insert(u);
    }
  }

  printf("%d\n", numbers.size());

  return 0;
}
```

Any idea of how this can be done in O(N)? I know I have to sort it before, but I can use this I just made:

```
bool compare(const vector<int> first, const vector<int> second) {
  if (first[0] == second[0]) return first[1] < second[1];
  return first[0] < second[0];
}

sort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), compare);
```

So it'd be O(log N + N).

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: This is not "summing" intervals, this is computing their union.

Comment: @larsmans really the _size_ of their unions, but good point!

Comment: You could do it with a `std::map`. Or, if you know the range (i.e. all numbers will be between 0 and 1000), you could use a simple array of `bool` or an array of bytes that you treat as a bit field.

Comment: Look up [interval trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), they may be of interest when solving this problem.

Comment: If `N` is the number of intervals, then my suggestion won't work. I thought `N` was the number of items in all of the intervals.

Comment: you need to somehow sort the intervals so this is not possible in O(N).

Comment: You can also do it in `O(k^2)`, where `k` is the number of segments. Think of this as lines, and whenever you get a new interval, you check whether it intersects with a previous line, if not, then add it in the list. If it does, then update accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If `n` is the number of intervals then I don't think that there is a way to do this that is not `O(n log(n))`.

But if we're willing to face that, the first step is to sort the intervals by their left-hand value.  (This takes time `O(n log(n))`.)  Then you try to compute a minimal set of intervals in the union according to the following pseudo-code

```
answer = 0
while intervals left
    (min, max) = next interval
    while intervals left and min of next interval < max:
        if max < max of next interval:
            max = max of next interval
        move forward in interval list
    # the next interval is [min..max]
    answer += max - min + 1
```

(This code is linear in the number of intervals, the non-linear piece is sorting it.)

Comment: There are faster than nlog(n) algorithms to sort integers, but otherwise, I totally agree that first you sort, then you merge in O(n).

Comment: @rrenaud there are faster than `O(n log(n))` algorithms to sort restricted sets of integers.  However arbitrary integers are a different story.

Comment: That is not my understanding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_sorting#Trans-dichotomous_algorithms

Answer (score 1):

I did it time ago in OCaml, here's the code:

```
let rec calc c l1 l2 =
  match c,l1,l2 with                            
      None, (f1,t1) :: y1, ((f2,t2) :: y2 as n2) when f1 < f2 -> calc (Some (f1,t1)) y1 n2
    | None, n1, (f2,t2) :: y2 -> calc (Some (f2,t2)) n1 y2
    | None, _, _ -> []
    | (Some (fc,tc) as cur), (f1,t1) :: y1, ((f2,t2) :: y2 as n2) when t1 <= fc -> calc cur y1 n2
    | (Some (fc,tc) as cur), ((f1,t1) :: y1 as n1), (f2,t2) :: y2 when t2 <= fc -> calc cur n1 y2
    | Some (fc,tc), (f1,t1) :: y1, ((f2,t2) :: y2 as n2) when f1 <= tc && t1 > fc -> calc (Some (fc,t1)) y1 n2
    | Some (fc,tc), ((f1,t1) :: y1 as n1), (f2,t2) :: y2 when f2 <= tc && t2 > fc -> calc (Some (fc,t2)) n1 y2
    | Some (fc,tc), (f1,t1) :: y1, ((f2,t2) :: y2 as n2) when f1 < f2 -> [fc,tc] @ calc (Some (f1,t1)) y1 n2
    | Some (fc,tc), (t :: e as n1), (f2,t2) :: y2 -> [fc,tc] @ calc (Some (f2,t2)) n1 y2
    | Some (fc,tc), [], (f,t) :: tr when f <= tc && t > tc -> calc (Some (fc,t)) [] tr
    | Some (fc,tc), [], (f,t) :: tr when f <= tc && t <= tc -> calc (Some (fc,tc)) [] tr
    | Some (fc,tc), [], x -> [fc,tc] @ x
    | Some (fc,tc), (f,t) :: tr, [] when f <= tc && t > tc -> calc (Some (fc,t)) tr []
    | Some (fc,tc), (f,t) :: tr, [] when f <= tc && t <= tc -> calc (Some (fc,tc)) tr []
    | Some (fc,tc), x, [] -> [fc,tc] @ x
```

This computes the union of two ranges (which are two arbitrary sets of couple of elements) and it's O(N+M) (N and M are the number of single intervals in each set). Result is sorted.

After this you can easily compute the list in linear time:

```
List.fold_left (fun a (f,t) -> for i = f to t do a := !a @ [Int i] done; a) (ref []) range
```

Ok, this is OCaml but I had it ready so maybe it will be useful to you, especially on tricky part that merges intervals by deleting overlapping parts, since I spent some time to figure out the algorithm but I couldn't describe it to you in metacode (as you can see from implementation).

Comment: The name is just a reminiscence of the old code, this function was inside the specific block that cared about the merge of intervals so its intent was clear :) I even have the code for intersection if needed.

Comment: Are you sure this is linear? I don't fully understand your code, but I think it would merge the first two elements, then the result with the third one, etc., which would make it quadratic.

Comment: No, it goes through the lists and always remove at least one entry, merging when needed. The worst case is when just one element from one of two lists is removed which is O(N+M)

Comment: Yeah, I get that `calc` is linear. But I was talking about the final result, which basically works on many lists, where each contains only one element. And I think that's quadratic in the number of lists.

Comment: They are not lists, they are tuples of 2 elements (pairs) so it's actually linear on the number of tuples. Of course if a tuple is like `1..10` you have to generate 10 elements but this is indeed the lower bound, you can't do better.

Comment: @Jack - please explain this solution in more detail. Just as svick I have the feeling it is quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best complexity you can achieve here is O(N*log(N)) where N is the number of intervals. The solution is not very hard - you need to first sort the intervals by their beginning and then do another linear pass to compute their union. I will try to write some code in c++:

```
struct Interval {
  int from, to;
  bool operator<(const Interval& other) const {
    if(from != other.from) {
      return from < other.from;
    }
    return to < other.to;
  }
};

int main() {
  vector<Interval> intervals;
  sort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end());

  int current_position = intervals[0].from;
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < intervals.size(); ++i) {
    if (intervals[i].to < current_position) {
      continue;
    } else if (intervals[i].from <= current_position) {
      sum += intervals[i].to - current_position + 1;
      current_position = intervals[i].to + 1;
    } else {
      sum += intervals[i].to - intervals[i].from + 1;
      current_position = intervals[i].to + 1;
    }
  }
  std::cout << sum << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1..6
12..15
6..9
3..8

Worked for a few cases but not that one, it should print out 13, but 12 comes out.

Comment: @user996056 - fixed: http://ideone.com/bZ9Pc I had an error in the condition intervals[i].to <= current_position the comparison needs to be strict. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's be clear about what `N` is - is it the number of segments?

If this is the case, then you can't always do it - simply printing out the number of individual numbers within all the segments - call that m - takes O(m) time.  The fastest algorithm, then, can't be better than O(m+n)

Comment: O(M+N) is still considered O(N) complexity, unless of course M is defined as N^2 or greater magnitude.

Comment: N is the number of intervals, yes.

Comment: @user996056 - What I'm getting at is that is this - do you want to print out every number in the union of intervals? Or do you just want to know the size?

Comment: @Thomas - Huh?  M is not a function of N, they're independent.

Comment: @spinning_plate That's not relevant to the computation of union of the range of values. Since this question is tagged as an algorithm question it seems unlikely his concern is about the fairly constant complexity of printing a list of numbers.

Comment: @Thomas -  I believe it's relevant to the askers understanding of the problem,

Comment: This solution is not correct - if you have 1..10 and 5..15 the output should be 15 instead of the 21 your solution would give,