# Counting number of days, given a collection of day ranges?

Tags: algorithm

Say I have the following ranges, in some list:

```
{ (1, 4), (6, 8), (2, 5), (1, 3) }
```

`(1, 4)` represents days 1, 2, 3, 4. `(6, 8)` represents days 6, 7, 8, and so on.

The goal is to find the total number of days that are listed in the collection of ranges -- for instance, in the above example, the answer would be 8, because days 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, and 5 are contained within the ranges.

This problem can be solved trivially by iterating through the days in each range and putting them in a HashSet, then returning the size of the HashSet. But is there any way to do it in O(n) time with respect to the number of range pairs? How about in O(n) time and with constant space? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Summing intervals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236889/summing-intervals)

Answer (score 1):

Sort the ranges in ascending order by their lower limits. You can probably do this in linear time since you're dealing with integers.

The rest is easy. Loop through the ranges once keeping track of numDays (initialized to zero) and largestDay (initialized to -INF). On reaching each interval (a, b):

if b > largestDay then
numDays <- numDays + b-max(a - 1, largestDay)
largestDay <- max(largestDay, b)

else nothing.

---

So, after sorting we have (1,4), (1,3), (2,5), (6,8)

(1,4): numDays  <- 0 + (4 - max(1 - 1, -INF)) = 4, largestDay <- max(-INF, 4) = 4

(1,3): b < largestDay, so no change.

(2,5): numDays <- 4 + (5 - max(2 - 1, 4)) = 5, largestDay <- 5

(6,8): numDays <- 5 + (8 - max(6-1, 5)) = 8, largestDay <- 8

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of the following algorithm is `O(n log n)` where `n` is the number of ranges.

1. Sort the ranges `(a, b)` lexicographically by increasing `a` then by decreasing `b`.

   ```
   Before: { (1, 4), (6, 8), (2, 5), (1, 3) }
   After:  { (1, 4), (1, 3), (2, 5), (6, 8) }
   ```
2. Collapse the sorted sequence of ranges into a potentially-shorter sequence of ranges, repeatedly merging consecutive `(a, b)` and `(c, d)` into `(a, max(b, d))` if `b >= c`.

   ```
   Before: { (1, 4), (1, 3), (2, 5), (6, 8) }
           { (1, 4), (2, 5), (6, 8) }
   After:  { (1, 5), (6, 8) }
   ```
3. Map the sequence of ranges to their sizes.

   ```
   Before: { (1, 5), (6, 8) }
   After:  { 5, 3 }
   ```
4. Sum the sizes to arrive at the total number of days.

   ```
   8
   ```